# I can save lives or destroy them

Tags: riddle

You can show me,
or you can give me away,
but you never can touch me.

You can find me between the family,
or between strangers when they first met.
I can save lives,
or destroy them.

Even a city and a day were named after me.

**What am I?**
**Please explain each line**

**With this hint it should be very easy (this is also just a second way to solve this riddle)**

> Once Lincoln was on the way to the ocean to find an antitoxin for his sick brother Victor.  Just before the arrival he got caught by pirates. But they were not attentive enough, so the escape was very easy.

Comment: I think the hint is a bit *too* much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> Love

Based on the hint:

> It's the capitalised letters in Lincoln/Ocean/Victor/Easy

You can show me,
or you can give me away,
but you never can touch me.

> Can show or give love, but it's intangible

You can find me between the family,

> Obvious enough

or between strangers when they first met.

> Love at first sight

I can save lives,
or destroy them.

Even a city and a day were named after me.

> Friday was named after Venus (Latin) and Aphrodite (Greek), both the respective goddesses of love.

Stuck on the city, although I'm sure there must be loads that would be relevant.
As pointed out by @AdmiralJota:

> Philadlphia is literally the city of brotherly love (from the Greek philos, "love" or "friendship", and adelphos, "brother" - TIL!).

Comment: Cuvynqrycuvn, perhaps?

Comment: I've one question to the hint. Did you take every word with the capital letter or did you used the Western Union Phonetic Alphabet? And to the last sentence **Even a city and a day were named after me.** the answer should be Paris (City of Love) and Valentine's Day

Comment: I've never even heard of the Western Union Phonetic Alphabet, so I just went with the capital letters that stood out!